# How to enable (disable) PPTP multi login (of a same account) on Linux?

Tags: vpn, pptp

I know there is `duplicate-cn` for OpenVPN. What's the similar setting in  PPP based VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None is similar in PPP's based on pppd. But there're workarounds as usual: running a check-script from ip-pre-up hook to check for a existing route to the same IP-address is one of them. Beware of race conditions though and use postcontrol as well.